# How to start Kong?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-9.4, kong

I am getting following error, when I tried to start Kong in Ubuntu

```
kong start [-c /path/to/kong.conf]
prefix directory /usr/local/kong not found, trying to create it
2017/11/05 21:11:41 [warn] ulimit is currently set to "1024". For better performance set it to at least "4096" using "ulimit -n"
Error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/pgmoon/init.lua:271: missing password, required for connect
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: yes but i am not sure where do i give the pass word as only  commands i executed are as below $ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install openssl libpcre3 procps perl
$ sudo dpkg -i kong-community-edition-0.11.1.*.deb   followed by kong start.  In fact I was not asked to set up user or password. so i am  confused

Comment: have you set up a postgres or cassandra Database and created an user for kong?

Comment: @Mathias - yes i have set up postgres and created user for kong

Answer (score 9):

on your psql run the following.

`CREATE USER kong; CREATE DATABASE kong OWNER kong;
ALTER USER kong WITH PASSWORD 'password';`

create a kong.config with following content.

`pg_user = kong
pg_password = password`

Run the migration and start kong (might require sudo)

`$ kong migrations up -c kong.config
$ kong start -c kong.config`

Comment: these are the general procedures/steps for starting kong, and not the solution to the above problem. @beebek this doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: @beebek your answer helped me.  The Kong installation docs don't mention creation of /etc/kong/kong.conf with the contents he posted, or running the "alter user" statement in Postgres.  I was having the same problem and this fixed it for me.

Comment: but this doesn't help with the db-less method kong specified on their docs

Answer (score 3):

your command is right, you just have to remove the "`[`" from the commands. That's an indication of optional argument in the kong-documentaion.
So the right command would just be:

```
kong start -c /path/to/your/kong.conf
```

Make sure to have updated and uncommented out the following fields in the `kong.conf` beforehand:

```
database = postgres (as in your case)
pg_host = your_host_address (127.0.0.1 by default)
pg_port = your_psql_port_address (5432 by default)
pg_user = your_psql_db_user (kong as per documentation of kong)
pg_password = your_psql_db_user's_password
pg_database = your_db_for_kong (kong as per documentation of kong)
```

If the proposed solution helped you, kindly close the question by accepting it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error, probably that your postgresql version is too old :

kong start -c kong.conf
Error: [postgres error] Kong requires PostgreSQL 9.5 or greater (currently using 9.2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying out the `kong migrations bootstrap` command by providing a custom path to the kong.conf file and I was getting the exact same error: `missing password, required for connect`

and in the verbose logs of `kong migrations bootstrap` I saw that the command always looks for the conf file in a set of pre-defined paths

```
kong migrations bootstrap ./kong.conf --v
2021/02/05 09:51:52 [verbose] Kong: 2.3.1
2021/02/05 09:51:52 [verbose] no config file found at /etc/kong/kong.conf
2021/02/05 09:51:52 [verbose] no config file found at /etc/kong.conf
2021/02/05 09:51:52 [verbose] no config file, skip loading
```

So I copied my kong.conf file to /etc/kong/ and it started working fine

Answer (score 0):

once you go with @beebek's solution then you need to change the corresponding changes on the config files and then bootstrap the migrations with the command

`kong migrations bootstrap`

If you are on ubuntu follow with this doc

[docs](https://docs.konghq.com/enterprise/2.3.x/deployment/installation/ubuntu/)

And if you are looking into the db-less docs, Here is one

[db-less](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.3.x/db-less-and-declarative-config/)